# Covert Table data to Array (formatting)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, jquery-templates

I am working in `signalR` .  I called one method from my controller used `signalR` . My method name is `getAllDates()`.

Please see below  for looking  my code

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                booking.server.getAllDates().done(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    var blogPosts = { Date: [data[0].Dates.toString(), data[1].Dates.toString(), data[2].Dates.toString(), data[3].Dates.toString(), data[4].Dates.toString()] }
                    $("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPosts).appendTo("#blogPostContainer");

                });
            });
```

My `getAllDates()` method return some date's from Database . That values return in the `data`  **(function (data))**. It's working perfectly . But i am using in Jquery Template , So I want the data's  must be add in array and look like some format  .The format liking for

```
var blogPosts = { Date: [data[0].Dates.toString(), data[1].Dates.toString(), data[2].Dates.toString(), data[3].Dates.toString(), data[4].Dates.toString()] }
```

My above code is working .but my code is  not standard. Because I am assigned  all values in manually .Please look the data index  `[data[0].Dates.toString(), data[1].Dates.toString(),` . The Index is assigned  0 ,1,2,etc from myself .but **I want to the index will assign when compile time using code .**

Any one  ,can you help this work to me ?

Sorry for my poor English . If any one understand in my question , then you should be edit this question . else, please tell me your doubt's !!!

**Answered :**

Finally I Finished it

```
var DateTempl = "";
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                booking.server.getAllDates().done(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (i != data.length - 1) {
                            DateTempl = DateTempl.concat(data[i].Dates + ",");
                        }
                        else {
                            DateTempl = DateTempl.concat(data[i].Dates);
                        }
                    }
                    var blogPosts = { Date: [DateTempl] }
                    $("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPosts).appendTo("#blogPostContainer");

                });
            });
```

I used to concat  and formatted in my dates for array inside of for loop . It's don !! yeah . Great work !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

i have never used signalR, so not sure if this helps, but have you tried replacing the number with a variable?
something like data[i] instead of data[0], or say data[i+1]? 
and then have i change according to what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey wait . I now use javascript concat . I think i will finishing it's shortly ....